# i need to find objects from array of object which satisfy some condition

Tags: mongoose, nodes, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

here is my mongoose code

```
var agentSchema = new Schema({
datejoined: Date,
,
product: [{
   
    fleet: String,
    payment: String,
```

}]
})
i want to get object from array product which satisfy the condition payment equals done

```
Agent.find({ _id: id, product: { $elemMatch: { payment: 'Done' } } })
```

i have tried this way

> `Agent.findone({ _id: id}).select( product: { $elemMatch: { payment: 'Done' } } }))`

the methods showing either one object or all the object irrespective of the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Agent.aggregate([{ $match: { _id: ObjectId(id) } }, { $unwind: "$product" },
    {
        $match: { 'product.payment': "Done" },
    },

]).then(prod => {
```

i was able to solve my own with this code